# SQLite database not updating with using Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

I think I'm updating my database wrong? It's not giving me a error, so it's probably something that I forgot to do or didn't notice. Anyways, I'm super stumped and the tutorial I was watching didn't have this problem.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['gen' , 'newacc'])
async def open_account(tendant):

    db = sqlite3.connect('leveling.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sqlupdate = (f'INSERT INTO leveling(user_id,xp, local_xp) VALUES(?,?,?)')

    val = (tendant.author.id, 0, 0)

    result = cursor.fetchall()
    await tendant.channel.send(result)
    cursor.execute(sqlupdate, val)
    db.close()

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: I think, you did not commit the changes. Try: `db.commit()` Add this above the `db.close()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `commit` your changes:

```
async def open_account(tendant):
    db = sqlite3.connect('leveling.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()

    val = (tendant.author.id, 0, 0)
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO leveling (user_id, xp, local_xp) VALUES(?, ?, ?)', val)
    
    # Save (commit) the changes
    db.commit()
    
    # We can close the connection if we are done with it.
    # Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
    db.close()
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Hey man, thanks! I tried to find docs on this but for some reason I haven't been able to find them. So thank you for the answer and thanks for the link to the docs!